# Downloading list of urls/files using loop - python

Tags: python, urllib3

I need to download approximately 1000 file/url and it will be hard to download them manually.

I tried to put the urls in a list and loop through the list but it I think my code overwrite the previous files and keep only the last item in the list

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

urls = ["http://url1.nt.gz" , "http://url2.nt.gz" , "http://url3.nt.gz"]
N =1; // counter helps me to rename the downloaded files
print "downloading with urllib"
for url in urls
 r = http.request('GET',url)
 Name =str(N+1) // each time increment the counter by one 
 with open("file"+Name+".nt.gz", "wb") as fcont:
                fcont.write(r.data)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print "downloading with urllib"
for url in urls
 r = http.request('GET',url)
 Name += N`

Answer (score 2):

You do not increment the counter - you add 1 without saving it back to `N`

Add `N += 1` after setting `Name`. You are missing a `:` after your for.

I am not quite sure where you have your 1000s of urls - I only see 3 in `urls`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

urls = ["http://url1.nt.gz" , "http://url2.nt.gz" , "http://url3.nt.gz"]
N =1  # counter helps me to rename the downloaded files
print "downloading with urllib"
for url in urls:
    r = http.request('GET',url)
    Name = str(N) 
    N += 1
    with open("file"+Name+".nt.gz", "wb") as fcont:
        fcont.write(r.data)
```

Comment: Thank you! just for simplicity I added only 3 urls on my list. Is there any simple way to read the list elements from a txt file? Oh my God, I can't imagine that I spent two days figuring out what is the problem on my code and its super simple!